# How to slice Torch images as numpy images

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, vision

I am working on a problem in which I have the coordinates to slice the image like

> X cordinate, Y coordinate, Height, width of the region to crop

So if if I have torch image obtained using

```
img = Variable(img.cuda())
```

how can we slice this image to get that specific area of image **[y:y+height, x:x+width]** .
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you can do it just the same way as in numpy.

Here is a short example:

```py
import torch
t = torch.rand(5, 5)
# original matrix
print(t)
h = 2
w = 2
x = 1
y = 1
# cropped out matrix
print(t[x:x+h, y:y+w])
```

Output:

```py
tensor([[ 0.5402,  0.4106,  0.9904,  0.9556,  0.2217],
        [ 0.4533,  0.6300,  0.5352,  0.2710,  0.4307],
        [ 0.6389,  0.5660,  0.1582,  0.5701,  0.1614],
        [ 0.1717,  0.4071,  0.4960,  0.2127,  0.5587],
        [ 0.9529,  0.2865,  0.6667,  0.7401,  0.3372]])
tensor([[ 0.6300,  0.5352],
        [ 0.5660,  0.1582]])
```

As you can see a *2x2* matrix is cropped out of `t`.

Comment: To add on top of that, when working with 2d images, you tensors will usually be 4d `[batch, feature, width, height]`, so you want to slice `t[:, :, width, height]` or `t[..., width, height]` (equivalent notation).

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution using this notation

```
img[:, :, y:y+height, x:x+width]
```

So the output would be a resized torch image. Thanks